# Installing django-lfs (lightning fast shop) using only pip and a virtual environment (instead of using zc.buildout)

Tags: django, web-applications, installation, django-lfs

[Here](http://docs.getlfs.com/en/latest/introduction/installation.html) is the installation of `django-lfs` using `zc.buildout`.

Does anyone know how you would best go about to install it without `zc.buildout` and using `pip` and a `virtual evnvironment` instead?

```
$ mkvirtualenv shop_project
(shop_project)$ pip install django-lfs
...
```

Comment: what are you asking? you've pretty much answered your own question - `pip install django-lfs` is how you'd do it.

Comment: Not at all. By installing I mean setting it up so it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-lfs-bootstrap](https://github.com/MrTango/django-lfs-bootstrap) is what I was looking for.